# android - Enable and Disable MenuItem on Navigation Drawer Activity Layout

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, menuitem, navigation-drawer

I have and app created using the Navigation Drawer `Activity` Layout.. And I need to **enable/disable** some items programmatically

[Menu Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oO2BF.jpg)

Example: I want to disable the Menu Item id nav_item2

I tried to do...

```
MenuItem nav_item2 = (MenuItem)findViewById(R.id.nav_item2);
nav_item2.setEnabled(false);
```

And it return a **NullPointerException** to me..

Also tried...

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    nav_item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.nav_item2);
    return true;
}
```

with the same **NullPointerException**

Someone know something to do?

nav_header_main_activity.xml (Generated with the Layout Creation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="199dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:src="@drawable/ciag" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="CIAg"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dev@ciag.org.br" />

</LinearLayout>
```

main_activity_navigation_drawer.xml (generated on the layout creation)

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_save"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_save"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="@string/nav_save" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
        android:icon="@drawable/chart_bar"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="@string/nav_graph" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_send"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        android:title="Enviar" />
</group>

<item android:title="Configurações">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_manage"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:title="@string/nav_manage" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_support"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_help"
            android:title="@string/nav_support" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can access menu from [**NavigationView.getMenu()**](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html#getMenu())

> Below is code :

```
NavigationView navigationView= findViewById(R.id.nav_id_in_layout)

Menu menuNav=navigationView.getMenu();
MenuItem nav_item2 = menuNav.findItem(R.id.nav_item2);
nav_item2.setEnabled(false)
```

Comment: i dont have navigationView variable.. how can i do to get it?

Comment: how you created your navigation drawer ? can you post xml

Answer (score 2):

Use below code

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.your_item_id).setEnabled(false);
```

More details is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html?hl=ru#getMenu())

Answer (score 1):

If you're using view binding you could do next thing:

```
binding.navigationDrawer.menu.children.forEach { menuItem ->
    menuItem.isEnabled = true // or false, what you need
}
```